# I have an error while creating Jhipster Microservice app

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry, jdl, jhipster-gateway

**

**ERROR! Error: spawn git ENOENT
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)**

**

I am very new at Jhipster and microservice architecture. While creating a Jhipster Microservice app. I take this message after I select  the native lang. of app.

Before take this error, I chose as below the questions. My choices are:

? May JHipster anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time? **No**
? Which *type* of application would you like to create? **Microservice application**
? Do you want to enable *microfrontends*?** Yes**
? What is the base name of your application? **category**
? Do you want to make it reactive with Spring WebFlux? **Yes**
? As you are running in a microservice architecture, on which port would like your server to run? It should be
unique to avoid port conflicts. **8081**
? What is your default Java package name?** com.sample.category**
? Which service discovery server do you want to use? **JHipster Registry (uses Eureka, provides Spring Cloud Config support and monitoring dashboards)**
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? **JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)**
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? **SQL (H2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, MSSQL)**
? Which *production* database would you like to use? **PostgreSQL**
? Which *development* database would you like to use? **H2 with disk-based persistence**
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? **Maven**
? Which other technologies would you like to use?
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? **No**
? Please choose the native language of the application **English**

Can somebody help me while solving this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: JHipster requires git, do you have it installed and available in path? Which nodejs version do you use?

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem. I didn't add the Git directory as an environmental variable, I needed to add it.